# ORA-00984: column not allowed here in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle

```
insert into sales_order
( orderno , clientno , orderdate , delyaddr , salesmanno , delytype , billyn , delydate , orderstatus) 
values 
(
    'O19001',
    'C00001',
    12-jun-2014,
    'Nadiad',
    'S00001',   
    'F',
    'N',
    20-jul-2014,
    'In Process'
);


desc sales_order;
Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 ORDERNO                                            VARCHAR2(6)
 CLIENTNO                                           VARCHAR2(6)
 ORDERDATE                                          DATE
 DELYADDR                                           VARCHAR2(25)
 SALESMANNO                                         VARCHAR2(6)
 DELYTYPE                                           CHAR(1)
 BILLYN                                             CHAR(1)
 DELYDATE                                           DATE
 ORDERSTATUS                                        VARCHAR2(10)
```

Comment: Date constants require single quotes.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because I got the ans.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use ISO format (YYYY-MM-DD) for the date literals. For example:

```
insert into sales_order (
  orderno , clientno , orderdate , delyaddr , 
  salesmanno , delytype , billyn , delydate , orderstatus) 
values (
    'O19001',
    'C00001',
    date '2014-06-12',
    'Nadiad',
    'S00001',   
    'F',
    'N',
    date '2014-07-20',
    'In Process'
);
```

Answer (score 2):

Always remember that `dates` are not string and not any specially treated data type. It is just they need to be input as string and convert to `date`.

You have three options to convert string to date as follows:

1. Use `date literal` - `date '2020-12-31'` (ISO standard format - `yyyy-mm-dd`)
2. Use `to_char` - `to_char('2020-12-31','yyyy-mm-dd')` - given date and applied format must match.
3. Use the string format as per `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` and oracle will do implicit conversion. If `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` is `'dd-mon-yyyy'` then you can use string `'31-dec-2020'` to insert it into some date column.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of the 12-jun-2014 string literal, you can use the following function in your SQL statement:

```
to_date('2014.07.12', 'yyyy.mm.dd')
```